# Store Gmail API token_key in java web application

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api

Am trying to create a web application that uses GMail API to access user's gmail  account. When user puts his gmail credentials, it generates an access_key and a token_key which is valid till the user log out the session.
But I want to take access permission once from user and later on I can access the account based on the access_key or token_key or any other parameter that was generated first time when user logged in. Am stuck in this.

How can I do this ?

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to access user information, without prompting with the consent screen, after the first time authorization, use "offline access". Check this link  https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Comment: Can I get alert from gmail when new email arrives or how google api will let an application know when new email arrives ?